# table mapping from coma separated text

Tags: php, mysql, database

I have more than 25K record in mysql database

**Posts** (table)

- post_id
- post_title
- post_content
- post_tag

post_tag in contain a coma separated string like this

- hukum,pertanian,kimia,h2so,jalan jalan,bahagia bersama
- bahagia selalu,jakarta,monas,h2s0
- cukup,baiklah

I need to create 2 more table and map the tag for posts

**Tags**(table)

- tag_id
- tag

**Posttag**(table)

- tag_id
- post_id

how to do this in mysql syntax or php maybe?

Thank you so much

Comment: I suggest you to code yourself and then show it to us so we can help you. Basically what you need is:

1. Create tags table(id,tag).
2. Insert into tags by doing a distinct of those tags in post.
3. Create your posttag table.
4. Use a join between posts and tags to insert those rows into your posttag table.
Try to do that yourself and then ask here if you have any problems on that.

Comment: @AndoitzJordán Did you actually earn reputations to change your answer into a comment here ;) just kidding ;)

Answer (score 0):

Create tags table (assuming tag_id is auto_increment)

```
insert into tags (tag) select distinct(post_tag) from posts;
```

This'll insert unique tag entries into the 'tags' table

Now you create your 'posttag' table

```
insert into posttag select tag_id, post_id from posts join tags on  
posts.post_tag=tags.tag;
```